# Modern UI Pie Chart Doesn't Show Data

Tags: wpf, charts

I am following all steps listed on this link,
https://modernuicharts.codeplex.com/documentation
but it gives below error  and only title and subtitle show up no chart

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error     'ChartBase' TargetType does not match type of element
>   'PieChart'.   MteroChartsModern   c:\users\sesa388372\documents\visual
>   studio
>   2015\Projects\MteroChartsModern\MteroChartsModern\Application.xaml    9

My xaml code:

```
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <chart:PieChart
    Style="{StaticResource MinimalChartStyle}"
    ChartTitle="Minimal Pie Chart"
    ChartSubTitle="Chart with fixed width and height"
    SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}" >
        <chart:PieChart.Series>
            <chart:ChartSeries
            SeriesTitle="Errors"
            DisplayMember="Category"
            ValueMember="Number"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Errors}" />
        </chart:PieChart.Series>
    </chart:PieChart>
</Grid> </Window>
```

Application.xaml

```
StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary >
        <Style x:Key="MinimalChartStyle" TargetType="chart:ChartBase">
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="500"/>
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="500"/>
        </Style>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is caused since you are defining the Style for `TargetType="chart:ChartBase"` and what you are using is `chart:PieChart`.

Please define a style for `chart:PieChart` like  :

```
StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary >
        <Style x:Key="MinimalChartStyle" TargetType="chart:PieChart">
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="500"/>
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="500"/>
        </Style>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```